# How do I check for duplicate file from URL before downloading

Tags: java, file, url, duplicates, download

I have thousands of images in my folder on my computer and I am trying to find out how can I check if the file from given URL is already downloaded. Is is possible somehow?

This only give me size of the file.

```
URL url = new URL("http://test.com/test.jpg");
url.openConnection().getContentLength();
```

For duplicate file I use

```
FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2)
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: If you store all the files in the same folder and don't rename them (store them with the same name as is in the URL), you could just check if the file with that name already exists before downloading it..

Comment: If files are coming from different URLs you could save the file giving it the name of the result of a hash function of the contents. If two files have the same hash then it is very likely that they are the same content.

Comment: It is more complicated. The struggle is, that the files I am downloading can be same by content, but they can have different names. I am trying to find solution better than checking the file after downloading.

Comment: Brett Walker: But how can I get the hash from content of a file I haven't downloaded yet?

Comment: You can use the If-Modified-Since HTTP header (if supported by the server), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setIfModifiedSince%28long%29 . The HTTP return code should be 304.

Comment: @Filip, How else are you going to determine if they are the same or different to what you have, if you don't download them. Where you got the file from won't know if they are different.

Comment: Do you need to check only for unique URLs or also for same content? If the primer is the case you could also try to utilize [DRUM](http://irl.cs.tamu.edu/people/hsin-tsang/papers/www2008.pdf) or [VEUNIQ](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~nivio/papers/spire11.pdf), though I feel this might be a bit to big for your needs. You could also create a hash from the bytes of the content and send them to these stores. Depending on the number of URLs/pictures you need to check, this might however be quite a massive overhead. Maybe a simple cache which you feed with the hashes of the URLs/pictures is enough

Answer (score 2):

If you have a base URL and store files with the same filenames. You can ask the server if it's worth downloading the image again thanks to the file modification time and the If-Modified-Since HTTP Header.

```java
    File f = new File();// the file to download
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.test.com/"+f.getName()).openConnection();
    // Add the IfModifiedSince HEADER
    con.setIfModifiedSince(f.lastModified());
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.connect();
    if(con.getResponseCode() == 304) {
        System.out.println(f+ " : already downloaded");
    } else {
        // Download the content again and store the image again
    }
```

It will work if the modification time of the local file has been left intact since the first download and if the server supports IfModifiedSince header.

If you don't know how to match the filename and the URL then there is no obvious way to it.

You could do some experiments with a fast HEAD request and extract some relevant informations like :

- Content-Length
- Last-Modified
- ETag

Content-Length + Last-Modified could be a good match.

For ETags if you know how the http server builds the ETag you could try to build it on your side (on all your local files) and use it as a value to compare.
Some info on ETags:

- http://bitworking.org/news/150/REST-Tip-Deep-etags-give-you-more-benefits
- https://serverfault.com/questions/120538/etag-configuration-with-multiple-apache-servers-or-cdn-how-does-google-do-etag

Unfortunately ETag can be constructed with informations only visible to server (inode number) so it will be impossible for you to rebuild it.

It will certainly be easier/faster to download your files again.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't download the file you can't compare it with another.

Otherwise you can store the content you downloaded in a temp file:

```
File temp = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectory(), "temp");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, temp);
```

then loop through your existing files and call:

```
FileUtils.contentEquals(temp, existingFile)
```

In the end you would want either to keep or delete the temp file.

Of course this is not very fast. If you have thousands of files, you could save their hashes in a file and use that instead of `FileUtils.contentEquals`.

Comment: It doesn't really provide a solution. Requirement was to not download the file(temp or not temp still downloading whole file)

Comment: @zubergu Can you quote where you saw that requirement in the question?

Comment: err, title? How do I check for duplicate file from URL **before** downloading? And no, I didn't care enough to downvote.